# tax_input in wp_insert_post partly not working

Tags: wp-insert-post

I'm inserting a post via wp_insert_post() and in the $args the tax_input looks like this:

```
'tax_input' => array(
    "programmas" => 'Modern Family',
    "zenders" => 'ABC',
),
```

But what is happening: the "programmas" is correctly inserted but the "zenders" is not. I'm 100% sure that I've spelled these custom taxonomies correctly. When running the function, a post is correctly inserted except for the "zenders" part.

I have all the capabilities, because I am the administrator and I've inserted my user id in the "post_author" part.

Answer (score 1):

Try to append it in array, like this:
see this: [Insert post with custom taxonomy and post meta data](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#user-contributed-notes)

```
'tax_input' => array(
    "programmas" => array('Modern Family'),
    "zenders" => array('ABC'),
),
```